# How to increase the length of the header in Email::MIME?

Tags: perl, email, mime

I am using `Email::MIME` to generate an e-mail.
I am able to generate a header using:

```
$email->header_str_set('some-label', @my-array);
```

To problem is that, if the output is longer than 70 characters, it splits the result in 2 or 3 lines. I need it to be in a single line.

I've looked at the `Email::MIME` documentation, and I've found that:

*...The header_str parameter is a list of headers pairs to include in the message. The value for each pair is expected to be a text string that will be MIME-encoded as needed. Alternatively it can be an object with as_mime_string method which implements conversion of that object to MIME-encoded string. That object method is called with two named input parameters: charset and header_name_length*

I searched a lot, but I didn't find how to change the value of this variable.

Any ideas?

I've tried to use something like:

```
$email->header_name_length_set(100);
```

but it says that the object method can not be located.

Comment: The quoted passage says you can provide an object to `header_str` instead of a string. The object's class must provide a method called `as_mime_string`. That method *that you write* is provided with a length. In other words, Email::MIME tells your code how long the header can be. Not the other way around.

Comment: It [isn't](https://metacpan.org/release/RJBS/Email-MIME-1.953/source/lib/Email/MIME/Encode.pm#L34) configurable. Not posting this as an answer since I don't why it restricts the line length.

Comment: Re "*I need it to be in a single line.*", Why? Do you have a bug somewhere? Shouldn't you fix that bug instead?

Answer (score 5):

The email format has a limit on how long a line can be. To cite from [RFC 5322 section 2.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-2.1.1):

> There are two limits that this specification places on the number of
> characters in a line.  Each line of characters MUST be no more than
> 998 characters, and **SHOULD be no more than 78 characters**, excluding
> the CRLF.

And what you observe as a new line is called "header folding". This is only used to adhere to the length limitations of the line. A proper user agent on the recipients site will understand this concept and unfold the lines. See also [section 2.2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-2.2.3).

> I need it to be in a single line.

You probably should fix the code which requires this to be a single line since it makes the wrong assumptions on how mail works.

And, looking at the code of Email::MIME I think that this behavior is hard-coded and cannot be changed with some simple setting.

> *That object method is called with two named input parameters: charset and header_name_length* ...

`header_name_length` has nothing to do with the length of the header line. It is only used to specify the length of the header name in "name: value" so that it does not get encoded but only the value.